# how do I prove that $∡ (ℓ, m) + ∡ (m, n) = ∡ (ℓ, n)$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

For all concurrent lines ℓ, m, and n, regardless of configuration. We define the directed angle to be the measure of the angle starting from ℓ and ending at m, measured counterclockwise. So I came across definition of directed angles and it really seems counterintuitive to me, I'm struggling to prove this following formula  $$∡ (ℓ, m) + ∡ (m, n) = ∡ (ℓ, n)$$ as I said it seems incredibly easy thing to do, but not for stupid person like I am. It seems that I need to check so many various cases.

And in 3-dimensions I would never think that such a statement was true.

Comment: Are the three lines concurrent? How is the angle between two lines defined?

Comment: For all concurrent lines ℓ, m, and n, regardless of configuration. We define the directed angle to be the measure of the angle starting from ℓ and ending at m, measured counterclockwise.It came from this [link](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Directed-Angles/Directed-Angles.pdf) after all what I've done I sincerely believe that this doesn't stand in R3. In R2, the proof is obvious, but I thought it was applicable to R3, but I can't prove it, so mb It's just on the plane.

Comment: Please add this clarification to the body of your question.

Comment: It s obvious that the statement applies only to  coplanar lines.

Comment: Is it not axiomatic?  If the measurement of an angle is to have any meaning it must be that the angle of $l,n$ be what it is whether we drew the line $m$ or not.  And we have to be able to take two angle $l,m$ and $m_1, k$ and construct a unique angle by aligning $m$ with $m_1$.  Now we *could* define so non-linear way of measuring angles but.... *why*.  If we *can* define and linear additional one surely we *SHOULD*, shouldn't we?  And clearly we *can*.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are only two cases to be considered (ignoring degenerate cases when some lines coincide):

1. Starting rotating counterclockwise from $l$ we meet $m$ first.
2. Starting rotating counterclockwise from $l$ we meet $n$ first. In this case the sum $\angle(l,m)+\angle(m,n)$ exceeds $180^{\circ}$ and when we take it modulo $180$ (I saw in the link that we should do it) we get what we want.